# Global http proxy for OSX

Tags: macos, proxy

At work I have a mac and a PC. We access the internet through an http proxy. My PC has the proxy set up such that every application works with the proxy just fine. The mac I have entered the proxy server in network settings but only certain apps take note. Browsers do work but other apps like terminal, and my IDE (Php storm) do not respect the system proxy settings. Some apps have their own settings but at least in the case of PHP Storm it does not work.

Is there any way to get my all of my apps to respect the system proxy settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than having those applications honor the "System Proxy settings", no.

the way to coerce them, would be to make use of transparent proxy redirects on the gateway, but that is a different subject.

The reason windows application might honor the system settings, is that they "usually" make use of the Windows APIs for HTTP/etc. and those will then honor the system proxy settings through the Windows APIs.

On MacOSX, which is based on *BSD, the proxy settings are mostly just a setting, as the applications have direct network/socket access.

YEs, I know, it's painful to check each application on MacOSX.